# How to create a script to sync notes to files using Geeknote

Tags: bash

I want to create a directory with my notes from Evernote in files with the Markdown format. I found out that this can be made using [Geeknote](http://www.geeknote.me/documentation/), but for each notebook each time.

How to create a bash script that synchronizes a directory, where each subdirectory is a different notebook, and inside these the markdown files?

While you make suggestions, I will keep this question updated.

The command to two-way sync using Geeknote is the following:

```
gnsync --path ~/Evernote/Ler --logpath ~/.log/geeknote.log --format markdown --notebook ".Ler" --two-way TWO_WAY
```

The command to list my notebooks is:

```
geeknote notebook-list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, mainly inspired by the answer of the question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/568697/how-to-create-a-script-to-sync-notes-to-files-using-geeknote).

I have created a file at /usr/bin with the following content:

```
#function sync_notebook {
#  gnsync --path ~/Evernote/$1 --logpath ~/.log/geeknote$1.log --format markdown --notebook "$1" --two-way TWO_WAY
#}

cd DIRECTORY_OF_MY_MARKDONW_FILES
for D in *
#     do sync_notebook $D
      do gnsync --path ~/Evernote/$D --logpath ~/.log/geeknote.log --format markdown --notebook "$D" --two-way TWO_WAY
      echo "$D"
done
```

Every time I want to sync the dataset I run the command from the command line.

I wish I knew how to automate it, tried crontab to no avail.